# How to monitor Multicast Forwording Cache changes in linux?

Tags: c, multicast, inotify, netlink, pim

Linux stores MFC table in the kernel, and users can display it  by /proc/net/ip_mr_cache. Multicast routing daemons, like pimd or frr, can add, del or modify it by setsockopt() function.

How to monitoring MFC changes in  linux using C code?

Now I want to write a program for monitoring MFC changes, and I noticed that:

1. Unicast route changes can be monitored via netlink. But I can not find similar way about MFC.
2. inotify() function seems can not be used in /proc filesystem. Is that true?